# How to crop canvas sides?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, crop, trim

Hi all im recently working on a project and I'm using HTML5, CSS3 and javascript.

I have a < canvas > element, and im feeding an < image > captured by the webcam.

```
var myCanvas, videoElement, frame;
```

I'm using p5Js libraries to feed the image every frame using the code below:

```
function setup()
    myCanvas = createCanvas(w,h);
    //...(setId(), setParent(),)
    videoElement = createCapture(VIDEO);
    //...(setParent(), setId(), setSize())
}
function draw(){

   frame = image(videoElement, 0, 0, canvasWidth,  canvasHeight);    
}
```

My question is how to crop the sides of the canvas as shown in the Figure 1 below:

[image: Figure 1]

Note that I do not want to crop the image since if I do the cropping on the canvas that would be also implemented in the image.

For now im using the CSS below but this is not exactly what Im looking for:

```
document.getElementById("editingCanvas-element").style.border = "1px solid black";
document.getElementById("editingCanvas-element").style.borderRadius = "100px 100px";
```

Any help would be appriciatable, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a smaller canvas element, so you need to define it in the setup. Supposing you know how much you want to crop, the width of your canvas should be `w - 2*crop`

Then when painting the video: `frame = image(videoElement, -crop, 0, canvasWidth,  canvasHeight);` I hope this is what you need.

```js
function setup()
    myCanvas = createCanvas(w - 2*crop,h);
    //...(setId(), setParent(),)
    videoElement = createCapture(VIDEO);
    //...(setParent(), setId(), setSize())
}
function draw(){

   frame = image(videoElement, -crop, 0, canvasWidth,  canvasHeight);    
}
```